# Wordpress: How to check is plugin active?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

How to check is plugin active in WordPress. I've installed easy-digital-downloads(edd). in directory: `/wp-content/plugins/easy-digital-downloads` and the plugin file is in `/wp-content/plugins/easy-digital-downloads/easy-digital-downloads.php`.
I tried this and I know that the plugin is active.:

```
if (is_plugin_active(get_home_url() . '/wp-content/plugins/easy-digital-downloads/easy-digital-downloads.php')) {
  echo 'plugin is active';
} else {
  echo 'plugin is not active';
}
```

The above code echoes that 'plugin is not active' but the plugin is active.

I think the problem is my dir to plugin address.

Comment: where are you hooking it?

Comment: excuse me. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: the `is_plugin_active` function must be hooked to admin_init or a later action

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need the full url, just want the path to the main plugin file from plugins directory.

```
function check_plugin_state() {
    if (is_plugin_active('easy-digital-downloads/easy-digital-downloads.php')) {
        echo 'plugin is active';
    }
    else {
        echo 'plugin is not active';
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'check_plugin_state');
```

Note: if you want this in front-end do not forget to add `include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';`

Answer (score 5):

Apart from using the WordPress function `is_plugin_active()`, you can use the PHP native function `class_exists()`.

In your case, you have to pass the Easy Digital Downloads main class name, which is `Easy_Digital_Downloads`. So, you have to write

```php
if(class_exists('Easy_Digital_Downloads')){
   echo 'plugin is active';
}else{
   echo 'plugin is not active';
}
```

Also, you can use the PHP native function `function_exists()`. You have to pass the Easy Digital Downloads main function `EDD()` as the parameter. The `EDD()` function is used to instantiate the Easy Digital Downloads plugin's main class. So, you can write

```php
if(function_exists('EDD')){
   echo 'plugin is active';
}else{
   echo 'plugin is not active';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another logic can be like this:

```
    $pluginsList = get_option( 'active_plugins' );
    $my_plugin = 'plugin-dir-name-in-plugins-dir-under-wp-content/plugin-name.php'; 
    if ( in_array( $my_plugin , $pluginsList ) ) {
        echo "MyPlugin is active";
    }else{
      echo "MyPlugin is not active"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest one liner

```
if (in_array('plugin_directory_here', array_map('dirname', get_option('active_plugins')), true)) {

}
```